# OpportunityLineItemSchedule Division picklist field missing

Tags: apex, opportunitylineitemschedule

**Background**

According to the Salesforce documentaion:

- [Salesforce Field Reference Guide: OpportunityLineItemSchedule](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfFieldRef.meta/sfFieldRef/salesforce_field_reference_OpportunityLineItemSchedule.htm)

The **OpportunityLineItemSchedule** object has a **Division** picklist field.

Yet when I run this code:

```
Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> schemaFieldMap = Schema.SObjectType.OpportunityLineItemSchedule.fields.getMap();
Map<String, Object> queriedFieldValues = new Map<String, Object>();
for (String fieldName: schemaFieldMap.keySet()) {
    System.debug(fieldName);
}
```

It does not appear.

**Questions**

1. Where has it gone?
2. What are the picklist options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Division field refers to the [Division](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_division.htm) object. It would only be available if you have the [Divisions](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_division.htm&type=5) feature enabled. Basically, really large organizations can have problems accessing records (typically accounts, contacts, leads, cases, and opportunities), and this feature alleviates that problem by assigning records to various "divisions" within your organization. Doing this doesn't restrict which records a user can see, but does limit the number of records they can query at once to help improve system performance. You can read more in the topics linked above.

Comment: Thanks. Why does the documentation say it's of type picklist if it's actually an object reference?

Comment: @Robs So, I don't have Divisions enabled in any org, but my guess is that it is the Division name, rather than an ID. Unfortunately, the standard object reference doesn't include the field, and the documentation on how it would work seems to be sparse. Regardless, unless you're going to go get this feature enabled, I wouldn't worry about it.